# Box2D random crash when adding joints

Tags: java, box2d

I'm currently working on a project which uses Box2D, when the player uses a certain key it should anchor to the ground. For that I use a weld joint, but when I add the joint the game will sometimes crash, it has a 1/10 change to crash.

The error I recieve:

```
Showing the controller
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
at org.jbox2d.dynamics.Island.add(Island.java:577)
at org.jbox2d.dynamics.World.solve(World.java:1073)
at org.jbox2d.dynamics.World.step(World.java:598)
```

The code for adding the joints:

```
WeldJointDef def = new WeldJointDef();
def.initialize(body, anchoredObject.body, body.getWorldCenter());
weldJoint = (WeldJoint) world.createJoint(def);
```

I still get the error if I synchronize it

Comment: Are you executing this joint creation code in another thread? If so, try to acquire a lock on the world as you step it and when you add the joint.

Comment: As far as I know I'm not doing it in another thread, I can still call OpenGL within the class. I tried to use step(0, 0, 0) and body.setactive(false), but it will still crash. 

Logging the thread where the joint is added: Thread[main,5,main]

Comment: Stepping with time zero is a very bad idea.

Comment: Well yeah, but sometimes you've got to try things :P

Comment: I'm not sure if you can add joints within the step. Such as in the code that executes when a collision is detected by Box2D and you installed a listener for that. Maybe you can't add them in the listener.

Comment: It's not being added in the listener. I've tried to step before and after the Player gets updated, but with no success.